# Prove that exists a sequence such that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}c_n= \infty$ and $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_n a_n < \infty $

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{a_n\}n \in \mathbb{N}$ a sequence of non-negative numbers such that 
$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n <\infty$. Prove that exists a sequence
$ \{c_n\}n \in \mathbb{N} $  of non-negative numbers such that
$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}c_n= \infty$ and 
$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_n a_n < \infty $

Comment: I am interested Daniel,..Where is the answer ?